# View pager loop with arraylist object

Tags: android, arraylist

I have a question, in my app I have a view pager(have arraylist A with 3 item to show 3 page on view pager),and I used view pager loop, i follow : [Viewpager looper](http://www.constant-learner.com/2014/08/looping-viewpager-small-hack-to-make.html)
And now I have arraylist B with 100 item, I want show value off item in arraylist B on view pager loop.

how I do?

```html
package com.creativei.viewpagerloop;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 private static final String LOG_TAG = "ViewPagerLoop";

 static ArrayList<data> arraydt = new ArrayList<data>();
 ArrayList<data> str = new ArrayList<data>();

 int Cur = 1;
 static int lastPage = 1;
 Button btnUp, btnDown;
 static int nextId;
 int id = 2;
 private ViewPager pager;

 private ArrayList<data> arraydt1= new ArrayList<data>();

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  str.add(new data("0", "hello0"));
  str.add(new data("1", "hello1"));
  str.add(new data("2", "hello2"));
  str.add(new data("3", "hello3"));
  str.add(new data("4", "hello4"));
  str.add(new data("5", "hello5"));
  str.add(new data("6", "hello6"));
  str.add(new data("7", "hello7"));
  str.add(new data("8", "hello8"));
  str.add(new data("9", "hello9"));

  arraydt.add(new data("1", "hello0"));
  arraydt.add(new data("2", "hello1"));
  arraydt.add(new data("3", "hello2"));
  

  pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
  TextView counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);

  SimpleViewPagerAdapter adapter = new SimpleViewPagerAdapter(this,
    getSupportFragmentManager(), pager, counter, arraydt);
  pager.setAdapter(adapter);
  pager.setOnPageChangeListener(adapter);
  pager.setCurrentItem(1, false);

  pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (position == 0) {
     pager.setCurrentItem(arraydt.size(), false);

    } else if (position == arraydt.size() + 1) {
     pager.setCurrentItem(1, false);
     // counter.setText("1");
    }
    //

    Log.d("POSITION", "" + position);
    Log.d("Id hien tai", "" + nextId);
    Log.d("ID", "" + id);

    // if (nextId == 0)
    if (nextId == 1) {

     if (position == 2) {
      id++;
      if (id == str.size()) {
       id = 0;
      }
      Log.d("+12 ", "" + id);
      Log.d("Id", str.get(id).getText());
       arraydt.set(1, str.get(id));

     } else if (position == 3) {
      id--;
      if (id < 0) {
       id = str.size() - 1;
      }
      Log.d("-13 ", "" + id);
      Log.d("Id", str.get(id).getText());
       arraydt.set(2, str.get(id));

     }
     // nextId = position;

    } else if (nextId == 2) {
     if (position == 3) {
      id++;
      if (id == str.size()) {
       id = 0;
      }
      Log.d("+23 ", "" + id);
      Log.d("Id", str.get(id).getText());
       arraydt.set(0, str.get(id));
     } else if (position == 1) {
      id--;
      if (id < 0) {
       id = str.size() - 1;
      }
      Log.d("-21 ", "" + id);
      Log.d("Id", str.get(id).getText());
       arraydt.set(2, str.get(id));

     }
     // nextId = position;

    } else if (nextId == 3) {
     if (position == 1) {
      id++;
      if (id == str.size()) {
       id = 0;
      }

      Log.d("+31 ", "" + id);
      Log.d("Id", str.get(id).getText());
      arraydt.set(1, str.get(id));

     } else if (position == 2) {
      id--;
      if (id < 0) {
       id = str.size() - 1;
      }
      Log.d("-32 ", "" + id);
      Log.d("Id", str.get(id).getText());
       arraydt.set(0, str.get(id));

     }
     // nextId = position;
    } else if (nextId == 0) {
     Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "000 " + nextId,
       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (nextId == 4) {
     Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "444 " + nextId,
       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    nextId = pager.getCurrentItem();

   }

   @Override
   public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

   @Override
   public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }
  });
 }

 public static class SimpleFragment extends Fragment {
  private int position;

  public SimpleFragment() {
   // this.position=postiton;
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
     false);
   // String content1 = getArguments().getString("content");
   int id1 = getArguments().getInt("position");
   // int id = Integer.parseInt(content1);
   // Log.d("Content", content1);
   LinearLayout llayout = (LinearLayout) rootView
     .findViewById(R.id.Llayout);
   TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());

   tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
   tv.setText(arraydt.get(id1).getText().toString()+" "+id1);
   llayout.addView(tv);
   return rootView;
  }
 }

 public static class SimpleViewPagerAdapter extends
   FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements OnPageChangeListener {
  private ArrayList<data> arraydt;
  private String[] content;
  private ViewPager pager;
  private TextView counter;
  private Context context;

  public SimpleViewPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm,
    ViewPager pager, TextView counter, ArrayList<data> arraydt) {

   super(fm);
   this.pager = pager;
   this.counter = counter;
   this.arraydt = arraydt;
   this.context = context;

  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
   SimpleFragment fragment = new SimpleFragment();

   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   int index = position - 1;
   if (position == 0) {
    index = arraydt.size() - 1;
   } else if (position == arraydt.size() + 1) {
    index = 0;
   }
   Log.d(LOG_TAG, "For page at position " + position
     + ",fetching item at index " + index);
   bundle.putInt("position", index);
   fragment.setArguments(bundle);

   return fragment;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
   return arraydt.size() + 2;
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageSelected(int position) {
   Log.d("nextId", "" + position);
   nextId = position;

  }

  private String makeCounterText(int pageNo) {
   return "Page " + pageNo + " of " + arraydt.size();
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
   Toast.makeText(context, "arg0: " + arg0, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
  }

 }
}
```

main_activity.xml

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.creativei.viewpagerloop.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/counter" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment.xml

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.creativei.viewpagerloop.SimpleFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Llayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why you don't just use the same mechanism? like you did with arraylist A.

Comment: because in my app arraylist B  is returned when I request to sever, and if i do it same array list A it will take much memory, i wan when show A2 i will load A1 if swipe left and A3 if swipe right and value of A1, A1  will run in turn in ArrayList B

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same mechanism but changing some logicto dynamically load your data, this is my suggestion:

Assuming that your ArrayList shouldn't exceeds 5 elements (to not take much memory).

For the first time you can load only 5 elements: `B99-B100-B1-B2-B3`.

The current page will be B1 and you already have the next and previous 2 pages (to prepare data when switching).

- If you switch to right (B1->B2): remove B99 and load B4 (in background), so your list become `B100-B1-B2-B3-B4`.
- If you switch to leftt (B1->B100): remove B3 and load B98 (in background), so your list become `B98-B99-B100-B1-B2`.

Notice that after updating your list, the position of your current/visible page will change. You must handle this.

Comment: Yes, That is my idea
I create an array of three objects above and use view pager loop to form one view pager have 5 page
I was able to capture events and swipe left to increase or decrease id view pager ArrayList B Ex: 0-1 -... 99-0-1 ... and vice versa ..... 0-99 0-99-98 -99.
but I have a problem with the update data A when increasing or decreasing the ArrayList of ArrayList id B.
can you help me?

Comment: I didn't understand the link between your *ArrayList A* and *ArrayList B*. Why you need to update *ArrayList A* when change your *ArrayList B* ?

Comment: because when i custom page fragment to set view pager adapter  I have to pass in an array,  and it will determine the page so i pass array list A

Comment: Rami you can check my code and give me your solution